# How to approach in creating a complex ADA compliant data table

Tags: html, accessibility

I have to create a data table that is ADA compliant. Which is not too hard. However when it comes to tables with layouts as the shown in the image below, I tend to worry how to go about it.

Currently, the table in the following image is not ADA compliant. The table portrays two rows of data. Each row has a table with headers enrolled, avg cum, etc. This inscribed table can have multiple rows (like a normal table).

Any ideas on how to program such a table that is ADA compliant, would be very helpful. You can help me in the form of a short snippet of code or suggesting any other simpler formats of the table other than the one in the picture.

[image: Example table]

Comment: What makes you think your table is not "ADA" compliant? Can you explain your issue?

Comment: What meant by not ADA compliant is that the table does not use the proper systax. As in, no thead, th, tbody, etc tags are used. And when I use the screen reader, its hard to understand if the inscribed table is part of the COMM 1010 section 001 group or is it an independent table. I want the screen reader to read it in such a way that it is clear to the user where the inscribed table belongs to. Hope that makes sense. @RokoC.Buljan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can make it accessible in two ways. Let us call the main records "classes" which includes instructor and session information, and inscribed table "enrolled" data table.

1) You can make the "enrolled" data table ( with headers enrolled, avg cum, etc) as nested table complete with its own headers inside "classes" tables. Also you can potentially also use nested headers and mark up your cells with headers tags. This would be compliant but challenging for accessibility.

2) you can separate the "enrolled" tables from "classes" tables and add a column which links corresponding rows to the "classes" records.

But these changes would not impart accessibility unless you use `<thead>` and `<th>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why the second row with 4 header cells and 4 data cells isn't at the end of the first row? I mean the table could have 15 columns instead of 11 currently. `Enrolled` would be the 12th header cells and you'd have a simple table to code.

Here are some hints for a more accessible table (according to WCAG 2.0, way more recent than Section 508 from 1998 which is still the current "ADA compliant" thing in USA, for a few months/years I guess)

- a caption in a `caption` element, first child of `table` element). Not WCAG 2.0 compliant anymore but still better than no caption: if your project manager doesn't want to add it visually for everybody (sighted people, partially sighted people using or not using a screen reader and blind people), caption can be visually hidden (so it's still read by screen readers)
  Relevant [WCAG 2.0 Technique H39: Using caption elements to associate data table captions with data tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H39.html)
- First row of header cells `th` in a `thead` (*à la* ZenCoding: `table > thead > tr > th*15`) with content from Subject to Avg cum GPA
- rows and rows of `td` in `tbody`
- as it's now a simple table, each `th` is the header cell for all data cells in its column thus you can and should/must add an attribute/value `scope="col"`. Relevant **[WCAG 2.0 Technique H63: Using the scope attribute to associate header cells and data cells in data tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H63.html)**

Without changing the structure of your table, it's a complex table:

- You still have 11 header cells in `thead`, plus in each "line" of data made of 3 rows `tr` Enrolled and 3 other cells should be header cells in the 2nd row (data in 1st and 3rd rows),
- `scope` must not be used as it isn't the header of all cells in its column
- `id/headers` association is the only way to associate data cells to its header cell(s). Relevant **[WCAG 2.0 Technique H43: Using id and headers attributes to associate data cells with header cells in data tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H43.html)**
  *tl;dr* each `th` has an id with some valid value and each `td` has a `header` attribute which value lists the value(s) of id of header cell(s) it's associated with (separated by a space). `th` could have header cells themselves and thus a `header` attribute, for example with 2 rows of `th` and `colspan`s in the first one.
  Here each `td` is associated with one `th`: one on the top for the first 11 ones of each row, the `th` just above the 12-15th ones for the 2nd part of each row.
  More complex tables are a hell to render accessible because it's so much time consuming and tedious so rule #1 is: try very hard to only have simple tables so it's simpler for everybody to understand (and also easier for a web developer to code accessibly and for a screen reader user to understand)
- Also with complex tables, you should add a `summary` attribute to the `table` element *if* your doctype is still HTML 4.01 or XHTML 1.0. Summary is deprecated in HTML5/HTML Living Standard as far as I know. Relevant [WCAG 2.0 Technique H73: Using the summary attribute of the table element to give an overview of data tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H73.html)

Comment: Thank you for your input, Filipe. The reason the table has structured in such a way is to indicate that table with header Enrolled belongs to the section COMM 1010 section 001 and such. More like the definition list - dl/dd tags.
It states that the class section 001 has such and such enrollments. There will be other tables inscribed that may have multiple rows. I am not quite sure to handle that. It would be great if you could find the time to through in an example.
Thanks!

Comment: I see. 2 examples of complex tables if I can't find the time anytime soon: [tngconsulting](http://www.tngconsulting.ca/wcag-2-0-examples-of-compliant-html-tables/) and [a11y Tips by Denis Boudreau](http://dboudreau.tumblr.com/post/82584262810/associate-cells-in-complex-data-tables-using-headers)